# Run entire model or validate with open model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I am creating Network Analyst tools for people who are very light users and need things to basically be buttons. Because of the way we use GIS this can't be done in a web application or any light form of GIS.  Each user has ArcGIS Desktop installed and the toolbar I am trying to create needs to be very user friendly. (point and click)

This toolbar essentially needs to be Network Analyst light with singular functionality.  I have all the tools created but I am having trouble creating a button that adds the Route as the Network Layer.  The problem is the model needs to be validated or I need to press "run entire model" for the route layer to be added.  I have also tried a python script and I can get it to work if I copy and paste the code through the python geoprocessing window.  If I add the script as a command and make a button it says it works but the route layer isn't added. Also, if I just open the model I run into the same problem with the layer not being added. In order for it to work I have to edit the model and use the model builder window to run the model.

My questions basically comes down to is there any way to create a command button that runs the entire model or validates the model before it is run? or a script that can validate a model? or has anyone else dealt with this and found a workaround?

The model is very basic... just the "Make Route Layer"tool.

Comment: So you've saved a model with the input parameters already specified? I'm not sure that you can trigger validation without either changing the parameters or manually doing it as you have.

Comment: Yeah,the parameters are preset since it will always use the same input analysis network .

Comment: So it is very weird but if I make the "Output Layer Name" a parameter under the Make Route Layer Tool it works..... even though there isn't actually a parameter to fill in since in the tool I told it to call it "Route."

Comment: My understanding is that tool validation is always run as a tool opens so what you are asking is unclear to me.